Names of equilateral non-equiangular polygons
Are there any special names given to polygons which are equilateral but not equiangular? e.g. the octagon shown in the answer to this question. Obviously a rhombus exists for quadrilaterals but I want to know if there are names for other polygons or a general term for all equilateral non-equiangular polygons.

A polygon that is both equilateral and equiangular is called regular. Besides "irregular", I could not come up with another good name for equilateral non-equiangular (or equiangular non-equilateral) polygons, not even in the case of rhombi or rectangles.

As a polygon that is both equilateral and equiangular is regular, then a polygon will not be regular if it is non-equiangular as at least one of the criteria is not met. All polygons that are not regular are irregular, and so for the name of equilateral but non-equiangular polygons, I just recommend calling the polygon an equilateral irregular polygon.
